# Search string using find command in bat file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file with which I can find certain string count and then display it for monitoring, my batch file works fine for static files but when the file name is dynamic like with latest date in the file name, it searches all the files instead of only 1 file(which should be the latest one)

my actual code

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set loc="D:\location\loc1\File Name*.dbg"
set val=
for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ('find /c /i "String name" %loc%') do (
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set val=%%~a
set val=!val:---------- D:\location\loc1\File Name*.dbg:=!
set val=!val: =!
echo. Thread,!val!
endlocal
)
```

Also I want to trim this part of the output

```
---------- D:\location\loc1\File Name*.dbg
```

Comment: What do you mean by "file name is dynamic" - file name changes on the file system? Or do you mean that you pass it as a parameter?

Comment: I mean how i can perform the task if filename created with "Date" in the file name... like if file created yesterday, it was "File Name01012018.dbg" and if created today "File Name02012018.dbg" and now i only want to search string in the file created today, if i use * it search all the files available with the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /o-d %loc%') do for /f %%b in ('find /c /i "String name" ^<"%%a"') do echo Thread,%%b&goto done
:done
```

should accomplish the task.

The `dir` outputs a filenames-only list of fully-qualified filenames in reverse-date sequence; the `"delims="` ensures the entire filename is assigned to `%%a`. When the very first filename is generated, the `find` locates and counts the target string and assigns the count to `%%b`. `echo` that preceded by `Thread,` and then break out of the `for` loops by using a `goto`.

Although the syntax `set loc="D:\location\loc1\File Name*.dbg"` is quite legal, `set "loc=D:\location\loc1\File Name*.dbg"` is preferred as the quotes delimit the string to be assigned, ensuring any invisible trailing spaces are not included in the value. If this convention is adopted, the `dir` sub-command requires `"%loc%"` to allow `loc` to contain separators.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get the file name for the file created "today",

- for example "String name_0102.dbg" you should compute the value of "today" and store it (or a substring of it) in a variable. Then when you try to match the file, you should use both the "String name" and the value of today, something like (do not use verbatim, this is just to illustrate the process):

  ```
  'find /c /i %string_name%%today% %loc%'
  ```
- or you need to hardcode the date in the find call:

  ```
  'find /c /i "String name_0102" %loc%'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for you:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "loc=D:\location\loc1"
Set "msk=File Name*.dbg"
CD /D "%loc%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
Set "MRF="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir/B/O-D/TC "%msk%"') Do If Defined MRF (GoTo :Next
) Else Set "MRF=%%A"
Exit /B

:Next
Set "Val="
For /F %%A In ('Find /I /C "String name"^<"%MRF%"') Do Set "Val=%%A"
If Defined Val (Echo Thread,%Val% & Pause)
```